# How to access list property in view of razor page

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, razor-pages

In the view page ( cshtml ) I would like to access the entity such as products detail, price or something in my case. First, for products model, it includes following properties :

```
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int? CatId { get; set; }
        public string ProductSdesc { get; set; }
        public string ProductLdesc { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        public bool? Instock { get; set; }
        public int Inventory { get; set; }

        public ProductCategories Cat { get; set; }
```

So I would like to access one of these properties in the view page ( cshtml)

Following is my code trying to get the property in the C# razor page.

```
public class ElectronicDetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly XYZshopping.Models.XYZEVEDBContext _context;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        [BindProperty]
        public IList<Products> Products { get; set; }

        public ElectronicDetailsModel(XYZshopping.Models.XYZEVEDBContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _context = context;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            //var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;

            Products = _context.Products.Where(p => p.CatId == 10).ToList();

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            Products = _context.Products.Where(p => p.CatId == 10).ToList();

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./TransferSToC");
        }
    }
```

What is it supposed to be like in view page to get, for example, Price or ProductSdesc..?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            @Model.Products.... < this part I am trying to implement...> How can I access the property in the C# (controller page) ??
        </form>
</div>
```

---

--edit--
To understand what I am trying to do, 
On browser, I want those to be visualized looking like this:
`Casio HandHeld Color1 TV 2.7 --> ProductSDec
$45.0000 --> Price`

Comment: Your `ElectronicDetailsModel` is named a "Model", but it looks like you're using it like a controller. Those `IActionResult` methods don't make sense in a model class. Where is your controller code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post">
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@product.Price</td>
            <td>@product.etc...</td>
        </tr>
    }
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products[i].Price)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</form>
```

Comment: Should I only use foreach or for in this case?

Comment: It depend if you want to use @Html helper